# send content via post as it comes into the database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have only taken a small draft from the side,

it is such that I must have sent some data in my database,

what I've read me to is that such textbox must have the same name throughout from the controller has and model,

**index.cshtml**

```
 @Html.TextBox("Email", null, new
   {
    @class = "form-control input-lg",
    placeholder = "Skriv email her",
    type = "email"
   })
```

**Kontocontroller.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateUsers(OpretBrugere brugere)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
     //Is that the right way that I must find out something with database or should I do it differently?
     var email = Request["Email"].ToString();
     var CreateAnAccount = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Email == email);
     if(CreateAnAccount != null)
     {
        brugere.Email = email;
     } 
  }
}
```

on my model have i **opretbrugere.cs**

```
public class OpretBrugere
{
   public int UserId { get; set; }

   public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

What do I wrong såden that it will not go into the database, as I said, I have much more to model and cshtml ago to be entered into the database, but I will make a brief description of the task that make it easy for you.

Comment: In your controller action you should take the EMAIL from the model... not from the request. MVC maps your POST to the MODEL parameter (in your case OpretBrugere brugere).

Answer (score 0):

It could be better if you use MVC's model binder. Do something like this:

In your view add your model `OpretBrugere` as view model

```
@model Mynamespace.OpretBrugere
```

and then use html helper to generate proper input like this:

```
@html.EditorFor(m=>m.Email)
```

then in your controller you could read data from action's parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateUsers(OpretBrugere brugere)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
      var email = brugere.Email; // user's submitted data is here
      // save to db or whatover you want
  }
}
```

Comment: What if I have more things to be in the database, so should I do it differently?

Comment: Just add your fields to your model and do same thing I have done with the `Email`

Comment: so it means that I have to make all my stuff to a was first name, last name and age and more.

Comment: Yes exactly. look at [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-a-model)